# How to identify duplicates in EF Core 3.1

Tags: select, group-by, duplicates, linq-to-entities, ef-core-3.1

The problem is as follow:

I have updated project to EF Core 3.1
My code to show duplicate email addresses in companies data base  stopped working.
This code no longer works after update:

```
cos = cos.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email)).GroupBy(c => c.Email).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp);

return View(await cos.ToListAsync());
```

I thinks this is the problem:

Before EF Core 3.0, this was done implicitly, so EF downloaded all result rows and then applied the LINQ GroupBy. However, this implicit behavior might let the programmer expect that the entire LINQ query is executed in SQL, with potentially enormous performance impact when the result set is rather large. For this reason, implicit client side evaluation of GroupBy was disabled completely in EF Core 3.0.

Do you know how to modify a.m. code to work with EF Core 3.1?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace group -> count -> ungroup query operations

```
.GroupBy(c => c.Email).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp)
```

which can't be translated to SQL currently (and also has no good potential SQL translation in the future) with self subquery counting the "key" matches, e.g.

```
.Where(c => cos.Count(c1 => c1.Email == c.Email) > 1)
```

Comment: Regretfully it is not working .

I have only 3 records in dB and after 1 minute I get message:

Your app has entered a break state

Comment: Well, that's the only way to get server side query. Not sure what `cos`  is here (I assume some `IQueryable`), eventually try replacing it in the above criteria with the corresponding `DbSet`. And of course you can always switch to the old client evaluation by doing `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList` before the original `GroupBy`.

Comment: Many thanks for guideline.
It worked ok this way:
`var cos = await _context.Cos.ToListAsync();              
  var cos2 = cos.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email)).GroupBy(c => c.Email).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp)   
  return View(cos2.ToList());`

Answer (score 2):

This works in ef core 3.1 and gets properly translated into SQL.

```
var result = (from p in _db.People
group p by p.FullName into g
where g.Count() > 1
select g.Key)
.SelectMany(key => _db.People
.Where(t => t.FullName.ToUpper() == key.ToUpper()))
```